# How do I get rid of this error caused by MVCAttribute routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I have MVC Attribute routing enabled alongside Convention routing. I get this error every time I run the application.

> The inline constraint resolver of type
>   'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following
>   inline constraint: 'string'. Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The inline
>   constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was
>   unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'string'.

Here is the stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The inline constraint resolver of type
>   'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following
>   inline constraint: 'string'.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.InlineRouteTemplateParser.GetInlineConstraint(Group
>   constraintGroup, Boolean isOptional, IInlineConstraintResolver
>   constraintResolver) +389
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.InlineRouteTemplateParser.ParseRouteTemplate(String
>   routeTemplate, IDictionary`2 defaults, IDictionary`2 constraints,
>   IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver) +488
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DirectRouteFactoryContext.CreateBuilder(String
>   template, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver) +308
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DirectRouteFactoryContext.CreateBuilderInternal(String
>   template) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DirectRouteFactoryContext.CreateBuilder(String
>   template) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute.System.Web.Mvc.Routing.IDirectRouteFactory.CreateRoute(DirectRouteFactoryContext
>   context) +80
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DefaultDirectRouteProvider.CreateRouteEntry(String
>   areaPrefix, String controllerPrefix, IDirectRouteFactory factory,
>   IReadOnlyCollection`1 actions, IInlineConstraintResolver
>   constraintResolver, Boolean targetIsAction) +115
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DefaultDirectRouteProvider.CreateRouteEntries(String
>   areaPrefix, String controllerPrefix, IReadOnlyCollection`1 factories,
>   IReadOnlyCollection`1 actions, IInlineConstraintResolver
>   constraintResolver, Boolean targetIsAction) +155
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DefaultDirectRouteProvider.GetActionDirectRoutes(ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IReadOnlyList`1 factories, IInlineConstraintResolver
>   constraintResolver) +188
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DefaultDirectRouteProvider.GetDirectRoutes(ControllerDescriptor
>   controllerDescriptor, IReadOnlyList`1 actionDescriptors,
>   IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver) +245
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddRouteEntries(SubRouteCollection
>   collector, IEnumerable`1 controllerTypes, IInlineConstraintResolver
>   constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider) +234
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.MapAttributeRoutes(RouteCollection
>   routes, IEnumerable`1 controllerTypes, IInlineConstraintResolver
>   constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider) +333
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.MapAttributeRoutes(RouteCollection
>   routes, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver,
>   IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider) +398
>   System.Web.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.MapAttributeRoutes(RouteCollection
>   routes, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver) +192
>   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionAttributeRoutingExtensions.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(RouteCollection
>   routes) +123
>   SocialManager.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in
>   c:\Users\Naser Dostdar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\SocialManager\SocialManager\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs:16 
>   SocialManager.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Users\Naser
>   Dostdar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\SocialManager\SocialManager\Global.asax.cs:18
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The inline constraint resolver of type
>   'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following
>   inline constraint: 'string'.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9942821
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +352
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The inline constraint resolver of type
>   'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following
>   inline constraint: 'string'.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9924184 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +261

And here is how my Route.Config file looks like:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(null, "Page{page}",
        new
        {
            controller = "Blogs",
            action = "Index",
            category =
                (string)null
        },
        new { page = @"\d+" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(null,
        "{category}",
        new { controller = "Blogs", action = "Edit", page = 1 }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(null,
        "{category}/Page{page}",
        new { controller = "Blogs", action = "List" },
        new { page = @"\d+" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**P.S:** I did not defined any MVC Attribute route in my project as of yet, just want to test enabling the MVC Attribute routing feature.

**Web API Version : 2.2**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Somewhere* you have defined an attribute route. Nothing else will cause this error. Where you've done that, you've used `string` as a route constraint. For example:

```
[Route("{foo:string}")]
```

However, `string` is not a valid route constraint, as *everything* in a route is a string. Long and short, find the route attribute(s) you defined that include `:string` and remove that.

Comment: Oops Chris, My bad!!! I really don't know when I did defined a route with a string constraint but yeah there was one and everything works fine now! Thank You!